# Angular modules dependency upon configuration

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app with 2 interfaces. One for users and other for admins. Most of the code is same and shared. For the part that differ I have a module for each interface.

I want to serve/build my app with different interface from the cli, instead of inserting those modules manually.

What I do now:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
     // other imports...
     UserModule
```

when I want to serve/build the app for an admin interface, I manually replace UserModule with AdminModule. This works when done, but I want to make an automation.

The logic suppose to be like this:

```
export function getInterfaceModule() {
  if (environment.mode === USER)
    return UserModule;
  else if (environment.mode === ADMIN)
    return AdminModule;
  return UserModule; // DEFAULT
};
```

Want I want to achieve is to be able to insert the return of getInterfaceModule() to "imports" of the main module. Like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
     // other imports...
     getInterfaceModule()
```

(which is obviously not working).

Comment: The thing to do is to deploy the app with both modules and use `guards` in the `Router` to restrict access in the admin views.

Comment: how about lazy load the modules as needed.

Comment: I'd say he wants the same route, but to display things differently, so no guards. The Lazy Load approach can be valid. Can't you have two files and replace them on your `angular.json`? I don't know if this is a valid way to handle, but you got me with dynamically loading modules.